# Derive power series for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ from $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$ is known and equals $\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Can I use this fact and derive the power series for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ from it, eg using $\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1+x}, x\neq\pm1$. Or must I derive it from the definition $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^k(0)}{k!}x^k$

Thanks in advance!
Alexander

Comment: Take the series for $1/(1-x)$ and substitute $x^2$ for $x$.

Comment: Noting that $|x|<1\implies |x^2|<1$.

Comment: Calculating the derivatives is doable, but thoroughly unpleasant. The substitution $t=x^2$ in the power series for $\frac{1}{1-t}$ in principle needs theoretical backup. Perhaps a suitable theorem has already been proved. You could also find the sum of the terms up to $(x^2)^{n-1}$. This is (for $x\ne \pm 1$) equal to $\frac{(x^2)^n}{1-x^2}$. For $|x|\lt 1$, it has limit $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$. Or maybe you are just expected to substitute and go on to the next question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First way:

$$\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac1{1-(x^2)}=1+(x^2)+(x^2)^2+\ldots=1+x^2+x^4+\ldots$$

Second way: using that

$$\frac1{1+x}=\frac1{1-(-x)}=1+(-x)+(-x)^2+(-x)^3+\ldots=1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots$$

we decompose by partial fractions

$$\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{1+x}\right)=
\frac12\left(1+x+x^2+\ldots+1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\left(2+2x^2+2x^4+\ldots\right)=1+x^2+x^4+\ldots$$